# Prove $0\le a<b\:\text{implies}\:0\le a^2<b^2\:\text{and}\:0\le \sqrt{a}<\sqrt{b}$

Tags: real-analysis

This proof can be done by using a contradiction. For proving a contradiction, if $0\le a<b$ implies $0>a^2\ge b^2\:\text{or}\:0>sqrt{a}\ge sqrt{b}$. If this is the right direction, then I would have to provide each case.

Comment: Surely you can start with the fact $\mathbb{R}$ is an ordered field, either by definition with basic rules as axioms or knowing that it could be constructed from $\mathbb{Q}$.  The basic property $c,d > 0 \implies c+d>0, c \cdot d > 0$ should be your starting point. Using $\log$, derivatives, etc. seems absurd and is in fact circular.  Why not use $0 \leqslant a < b \implies \int_a^b \frac{1}{2} x \, dx > 0 \implies b^2 - a^2 > 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:  $u^2-v^2=(u-v)(u+v)\,$, and if $u,v \ge 0$ then $u+v \ge 0$, so $u-v$ and $u^2-v^2$ have the same sign. Use that twice, once for $u=a, v=b$, then for $u=\sqrt{a}, b=\sqrt{b}\,$.

---

[ *EDIT* ]  For example, with $u=a, v=b$ where $a,b \ge 0\,$, it follows from the above that:

$$
a-b \le 0 \iff a^2-b^2 \le 0 \quad\style{font-family:inherit}{\text{which is the same as}}\quad a \le b \iff a^2 \le b^2
$$

Comment: I get the outline but what is the purpose of u^2-v^2?

Comment: @Z.Lamb I edited one of the cases into the answer. Main point is that $a \le b \iff a-b \le 0$, so the sign of the difference indicates the inequality between the two terms.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $0\leq a<b$.

Suppose $a^2\geq b^2$, then $a^2\geq b^2=b\cdot b>ab>a\cdot a=a^2$, which is a contradiction in itself ($a^2<a^2$ is not possible), so $a^2<b^2$.

Suppose $\sqrt{a}\geq \sqrt{b}$, then $a=\sqrt{a}\cdot \sqrt{a}\geq \sqrt{b}\cdot\sqrt{a}\geq\sqrt{b}\cdot \sqrt{b}=b$, which is in contradiction with $a<b$, so $\sqrt{a}<\sqrt{b}$.

Comment: The first contradiction is just bad presentation on your part. In that line you sort of prove directly that $b^2\ge a^2$, then add the noise that $a^2\ge b^2$ and conclude by contradiction that $b^2\ge a^2$. But you already knew that!